# Strategy to "solve" $A=BM$ where $A$, $B$ are rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, numerical-optimization

In an algorithm I am implementing, there is a relation of the type $A=BM$, where $A,B$ are known matrices with more rows than columns, and $M$ is an unknown square matrix. My question is how to choose $M$? I wrote "choose" because it comes down to a *choice*.

In the algorithm, it seems to be solved using $M=\text{pseudoinverse}(B)A$, which, from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936401/minimize-a-bm-for-m-matrix/1936739#1936739), corresponds to minimizing $\|A-BM\|$ for the Frobenius norm.

I am wondering if there are different expressions of $M$ which could make sense. Minimizing numerically $\|A-BM\|$ for any norm would be too costly given that typically $A\in\mathbb{R}^{500\times 100}$ so $M$ as 10000 coefficients...

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; I don't think you'll get closed form solutions for other generic norms.

You can look at your problem in basically two ways:

A natural perspective is to suggest $M$ a linear transformation of $A$ for some $X$ of appropriate dimensions with then

$$M=XA=XBM$$

and therefore you would want $XB=I$. Indeed choosing the pseudo-inverse is then natural with $[(B^T B)^{-1}B^T] B = I$.

In that case, $BM=BXA=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T A$ and indeed that is the $M$ such that $\| A-BM\|_F$ is minimized.

The other perspective is to pick another norm (nuclear norm, induced $2$-norm, ..., take a pick from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) and try to minimize it but (as far as I'm aware) it will typically not lead to a closed form for $M$ and you will indeed need to resort to numerical methods which apparently you do not want (note that the size of your problem is not really large so a numerical method is likely to work just fine).

The problem is then to justify the use of a specific norm over the one for which you have a closed form solution, this will depend on your application but may therefore limit the number of norms you may want to consider.

Comment: _TLDR_ : too long, didn't read? I don't think numerical methods will work fine to minimize a scalar function of 10000 variables! Even with 100 variables I did not get any result.

Comment: (TLDR was to rephrase the conclusion as a one liner not referring to the fact I hadn't read your questions). I should have added that the scale of your problem is still manageable with a method like gradient descent or some such (granted, I have not tried on your specific problem), I was thinking about models such as Neural Networks that successfully use (stochastic) gradient descent to train models with several million variables. That being said, if you want to be able to use an efficient optimization algorithm it also reduces the type of norm you could consider. (what algorithm did you use?)

Comment: I tried Nelder-Mead with Mathematica. I'll try other methods a bit later. Thank you.

Comment: yeah NM only works well up to 5-10 dimensions..